# Question About Collecting Power of $x^n$ in Taylor Expansion of $e^{\sin(x)}$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, taylor-expansion, power-series

**Theorem 1**
For real numbers $\left\{a_{j,k}\right\}_{j,k\ge 1},$ if

$$\sum_{j=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left|a_{j,k}\right|<\infty$$ then for any bijection $\sigma : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}^2$ we have that the sums
$$\sum_{j=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{j,k}
= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{j=1}^\infty a_{j,k} 
= \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{\sigma(n)}$$ all converge and are equal to one another.
Now in some post I saw
$$e^y=1+y+\frac12y^2+\frac16y^3+\frac1{24}y^4+\cdots\tag1$$and that$$\sin(x)=x-\frac16x^3+\cdots\tag2$$So, in the RHS of$(1)$ replace $y$ with the RHS of $(2)$ .
i.e
$$e^{\sin(x)}=1+\left(x-\frac16x^3+\cdots\right)+\frac12 \left(x-\frac16x^3+\cdots\right)^2+\frac16 \left(x-\frac16x^3+\cdots\right)^3+\cdots+$$
Now since series of $\sin(x)$ is absolutely convergence things like $\left(x-\frac16x^3+\cdots\right)^2$ can be computed in any order. so we can **collect** power of $x$ in $\left(x-\frac16x^3+\cdots\right)^2$ .
My question is about why we can do this on
$$e^{\sin(x)}=1+\left(x-\frac16x^3+\cdots\right)+\frac12 \left(x-\frac16x^3+\cdots\right)^2+\frac16 \left(x-\frac16x^3+\cdots\right)^3+\cdots+$$
if  we have
$$|1|+\left(|x|+|-\frac16x^3|+\cdots\right)+\frac12 \left(|x|+ |-\frac16x^3|+\cdots\right)^2+\cdots+\tag{3}$$ is finite then we can use above Theorem 1 and collect power of $x^n$.

So my question is sum in $(3)$ is indeed finite . Or there is something different thing that we are using there.

Edit:
Let $f(x)=\sum a_n x^n$ and $g(x)=\sum b_n x^n$. assume Radius of convergence of $\sum a_n x^n$ is enough for composition then we have$$f(g(x))=a_0+a_1 \left(\sum b_n x^n \right)^1+a_2 \left(\sum b_n x^n \right)^2 +\cdots$$ Now my question is about rearrange of this series. If it is always true that
$$|a_0|+a_1 \left(\sum |b_n x^n| \right)^1+a_2 \left(\sum |b_n x^n |\right)^2 +\cdots$$ Is finite then we can use theorem and it answers my question. If not then why we can rearrange?

Comment: The question in Edit seems to have a negative answer even for polynomials $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, because the right hand side has absolute values, whereas the left hand side has none of them.

Comment: Yes ! I edited that part !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The validity of the convergence of the rearrangement can be argued by the following facts about absolutely convergent series:

> Theorem A: Let $\{f_1,f_2,\ldots\}$ be a sequence of functions on $\mathbb{Z}_+$ (i.e. $\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$) such that
>
> - Each $f_n$ is one-to-one,
> - The ranges $Q_n=f_n(\mathbb{Z}_+)\subset\mathbb{Z}_+$
> - The collection of ranges $\{Q_1,Q_2,\ldots\}$ is a pairwise-disjoint collection of sets whose union is $\mathbb{Z}_+$
>   Let $\sum_na_n$ be an absolutely convergent series. Define
>   $$b_k(n)=a_{f_k(n)}, \qquad\text{for}\quad n\in\mathbb{Z}_+, k\in\mathbb{Z}_+$$
>
> 1. Then, for each $k$, $\sum_n b_k(n)$ is an absolutely convergent series.
> 2. If $b(k)=\sum_nb_k(n)$, then the series $\sum_kb(k)$ is absolutely convergence and
>    $\sum_kb(k)=\sum_na_n$

and

> Theorem B: Let $f(m,n)$ is a double sequence. Let $g:\mathbb{Z}_+\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}_+\times\mathbb{Z}_+$ be a bijective function and define the sequence $G(n)=f(g(n))$.
> The double series $\sum_{m, n}f(n, m)$ converges absolutely iff $\sum_nG(n)$ converges absolutely. Furthermore,
>
> 1. $\sum_{m, n}f(m,n) =\sum_nG(n)$.
> 2. $\sum_nf(m,n)$ converges absolutely for every $m$ and $\sum_mf(m, m)$ converges absolutely for every $n$, and
>    $$\sum_n\sum_mf(m, n)=\sum_m\sum_nf(m, n)=\sum_{m,n}f(m,n)$$

Theorem B follows from Theorem A. Full details can be found in Apostol, T. Mathematical Analysis, 2nd edition, Addison-Wesley, 1974, pp. 198, 201.

---

- The absolute convergence of the series $\sum_n\frac{1}{n!}(\sin x)^n$ is immediate as the series $\sum_n\frac{1}{n!}z^n$ has infinite radius of convergence.
- [Cauchy-Mertens product theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product) implies that $\Big(\sum_m\frac{(-1)^mx^{2m+1}}{(2m+1)!}\Big)^n$ converges to an absolutely convergent series
  $$\Big(\sum_m\frac{(-1)^mx^{2m+1}}{(2m+1)!}\Big)^n=\sum_k b_{k,m}x^k$$
  where the  coefficients $b_{k,m}$ that can be found by convolution ($m$-times) of the coefficients of the $\sin$ series with themselves.
- Applications of Theorem B and Theorem A allows for the rearrangement.

As for convergence of series (3) in the OP, similar arguments apply.

- Note that $\sum_n\frac{1}{(2n+1)!)}|x|^{2n+1}=\sinh(|x|)$ and convergence is absolutely.
- Thus $\exp(\sinh(|x|))=\sum_n\frac{1}{n!}\sinh^n(|x|)$ converges (the radius of convergence of $\exp$ being $\infty$.
  Now, by Cauchy's product theorem, for each $n\in\mathbb{Z}_+$, $\sinh^n(|x|)=\Big(\sum_m\frac{|x|^{2m+1}}{(2m+1)!}\Big)^n=\sum_m b_{m, n}|x|^m$ where the coefficients $b_{m, n}$ are obtained by convolution of the sequence $b_{2m}=0$, $b_{2m+1}=\frac{1}{(2m+1)!}$ with itself $n$-times. (Recall that for sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$, $(a*b)_n=\sum^n_{k=0}a_kb_{n-k}$).
- Then $\sum_n\sum_m b_{m, n}|x|^m$ converges (absolutely since all terms are nonnegative) and Theorems A and B apply.

---

More generally, consider the power series
\begin{align}
f(z)&=\sum^\infty_{n=0}a_nz^n,\qquad z\in B(0;R)\tag{1}\label{one}\\
g(z)&=\sum^\infty_{n=0}b_nz^n, \qquad x\in B(0;r)\tag{2}\label{two}
\end{align}
where $R>0$ and $r>0$ are the radii of convergence of $f$ and $g$ respectively. Notice that the series
$F(z)=\sum^\infty_{n=0}|a_n|z^n$ and $G(z)=\sum^\infty_{n=0}|b_n|z^n$ also have  radii of convergence $R$ and $r$ respectively.
Assume that $g(0)=b_0\in B(0;R)$; then there is $0<q<r$ such that
$$|g(z)|\leq G(|z|)<R,\qquad z\in B(0;q)$$
for power series are continuous (in fact infinitely differentiable).

It follows that
$ h(z):= f(g(z))$ and $H(z)=F(G(z))$ converge for all $z\in B(0;q)$; furthermore,
\begin{align}
|f(g(z))|\leq F(G(|z|)),\qquad z\in B(0;q)\tag{3}\label{three}
\end{align}

The power series (convergent to boot) of $h$ can be obtained by applications of Theorem A and B.

For each $n$,
$$\big(\sum^\infty_{m=0}b_mz^m\big)^n=\sum^\infty_{m=0}b^{*n}_m z^m, \qquad z\in B(0;r)$$
where $b^{*n}$ is the convolution of the sequence $b$ with itself. Hence
\begin{align}
h(z)&=\sum^\infty_{n=0}a_n\Big(\sum^\infty_{m=0}b_mz^m\Big)^n=\sum^\infty_{n=0}a_n\Big(\sum^\infty_{m=0}b^{*n}_mz^m\Big)\\
&=\sum^\infty_{m=0}\Big(\sum^\infty_{n=0}a_nb^{*n}_mz^m\Big)\\
&=\sum^\infty_{m=0}\Big(\sum^\infty_{n=0}a_nb^{*n}_m\Big)z^m
\end{align}

Iequality \eqref{three} takes the form
$$
\Big|\sum^\infty_{m=0}\Big(\sum^\infty_{n=0}a_nb^{*n}_m\Big)z^m\Big|\leq\sum^\infty_{m=0}\Big(\sum^\infty_{n=0}|a_n| (|b|)^{*n}_m\Big)|z|^m
$$

Comment: Yes . We can use theorem B here . But absolute convergence of  
 $G(n)=f(g(n))$.  or of
 double series $\sum_{m, n}f(n, m)$
is also question here. That I asked  as**sum in (3) is finite**?

Comment: @MeetPatel: I don't quite understand the question/issue in your comment. In any event, convergence of (3) follows along the same lines . Notice that  $\sum_m \frac{1}{(2m+1)!} |x|^{2m+1}=\sinh(|x|)$ (convergence if of course absolute since all terms are nonnegative). Cauchy's product theorem allows to express $(\sinh^n(|x|)$ as an absolute convergence  power series in $|x|$, that is $\sinh^n(|x|)=\sum_m b_{m, n}|x|^m$ where $(b_{m, n}:m\in\mathbb{Z}_+)$ is the $n$-times convolution of the sequence of coefficients of $\sinh(|x|)$ with isself. The rest follows from Theorems B and A.

Comment: @MeetPatel: ... and of course, the fact that the radius of convergence of $\exp$ is infty, thus $\exp(\sinh(|x|)$ converges.

Comment: Thank you ! your last edit for general series  allows us to use theorem B .

Answer (score 2):

Yes, $(3)$ is finite.
In fact, it can be evaluated in closed form:

$$
|1|+\left(|x|+|-\frac16x^3|+\cdots\right)+\frac12 \left(|x|+ |-\frac16x^3|+\cdots\right)^2+\cdots
\\ =
1+\left(|x|+\frac16|x|^3+\cdots\right)+\frac12 \left(|x|+\frac16|x|^3+\cdots\right)^2+\cdots
= e^{\sinh |x|}
$$

Comment: Is it true for any expansion ? We can collect term (rearrange) in composition of two series?

Comment: Strictly inside the radius of convergence, it is OK there.  In this case, radius of convergence is $+\infty$ for all $x$, so it is OK for all $x$.  But you are right.  The reason is that we have absolute convergence inside the radius of convergence.  (I do not say that it works for series other than power series, however.  For example, Dirichlet series may have a non-trivial region of conditional convergence.)

Comment: You said it is ok for (1)  We can collect term (rearrange) in composition of two series or for (2) sum with modulus as in my question are always finite for power series .

Answer (score 1):

Since
$$|x|+|-\frac16x^3|+\cdots\le e^{|x|},$$
the sum in (3) is finite because it is not bigger than
$$1+e^{|x|}+\frac 12 e^{2|x|}+\frac 16 e^{3|x|}+\dots=e^{e^{|x|}}.$$

---

Moreover, the book [Fich] contains the following general result.

Consider a function $y=f(x)$, which is expanded into a power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ in the interval $(-R,R)$. Moreover, let we have a function $\varphi(y)$, expanded into a power series $\varphi(y)=\sum_{m=0}^\infty h_my^m$ for $y\in (-\rho,\rho)$. If $|a_0|=|f(0)|<\rho$ then for a sufficiently small $x$ we have $|f(x)|<\rho$, so there is defined the composition function $\varphi(f(x))$. Thus if $|a_0|<\rho$ then the function $\varphi(f(x))$ in the neighborhood of the point $x=0$ can be expanded into a series of powers of $x$, substituting into $\sum_{m=0}^\infty h_my^m$ the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ instead of $y$, then recursively calculating all powers according to the standard series multiplication, and finally collecting the similar members.

After the proof is noted the following. The domain of $x$, for which our arguments ensure the possibility of the expansion of the function $\varphi(f(x))$ in a series of powers of $x$ is characterized by the inequality $\sum_{n=0}^\infty |a_nx^n|<\rho$ besides the requirement $|x|<R$.
If $R=+\infty$ then the second restriction can be omitted and if $\rho=+\infty$ then the first restriction can be omitted. ... In most applications of the theorem it suffices to know that the expansion holds for *small* values of $|x|$. But if the question of the whole application domain of the obtained series is of interest, then this question requires a special investigation.

*References*

[Fich] Grigorii Fichtenholz, *Differential and Integral Calculus*, v. II, 7-th edition, M.: Nauka, 1970. (in Russian)

Comment: Is it true for any expansion ? We can collect term (rearrange) in composition of two series?

Comment: @MeetPatel Are the series required to be absolutely convergent?

Comment: @MeetPatel I found some general theorem. I am going to write it soon.

Comment: I am interested in composition of power series . So yes ! series are absolutely convergent.

Comment: @MeetPatel I added the general result to the answer.

Comment: Can you explain how this result answer the question: Because **Rearrange** is the thing that I want to prove . I think your result say composition of two analytic function is analytic.

Comment: @MeetPatel Oh, maybe I misunderstood you. But the situation with the rearrangement of series is well known. Namely,
if the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges absolutely then it is easy to show that it converges to the same sum for any permutation of $a_n$'s. On the other hand, there is Riemann series theorem. See details,
for instance, in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3168169/why-are-the-sums-of-absolutely-convergent-series-not-affected-by-changing-the-or/3174367#3174367) my answer.

Comment: Please check my edit once.